# Re-sort WPF DataGrid after bounded Data has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I am looking for a way to **re-sort** my `DataGrid` when the underlying data has **changed**.

(The setting is quite standard: The DataGrid's `ItemSource` property is bound to an `ObservableCollection`; The columns are `DataGridTextColumns`; The data inside the DataGrid reacts correctly on changes inside the ObservableCollection; Sorting works fine when clicked with the mouse)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you explore `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: @WPF-it Now I did ;) You gave me the right hint and I was able to solve my problem with the `CollectionViewSource`. See my own answer to see what I did. Thank you !

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It took me the whole afternoon but I finally **found a solution** that is surprisingly *simple*, *short* and *efficient*:

To control the behaviors of the UI control in question (here a `DataGrid`) one might simply use a `CollectionViewSource`. It acts as a kind of representative for the UI control inside your ViewModel without completely breaking the MVMM pattern.

In the ViewModel declare both a `CollectionViewSource` and an ordinary `ObservableCollection<T>` and wrap the `CollectionViewSource` around the `ObservableCollection`:

```
// Gets or sets the CollectionViewSource
public CollectionViewSource ViewSource { get; set; }

// Gets or sets the ObservableCollection
public ObservableCollection<T> Collection { get; set; }

// Instantiates the objets.
public ViewModel () {

    this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    this.ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
    ViewSource.Source = this.Collection;
}
```

Then in the View part of the application you have nothing else to do as to bind the `ItemsSource` of the `CollectionControl` to the View property of the `CollectionViewSource` instead of directly to the `ObservableCollection`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource.View}" />
```

From this point on you can use the `CollectionViewSource` object in your ViewModel to directly manipulate the UI control in the View.

Sorting for example - as has been my primary problem - would look like this:

```
// Specify a sorting criteria for a particular column
ViewSource.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription ("columnName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

// Let the UI control refresh in order for changes to take place.
ViewSource.View.Refresh();
```

You see, very very simple and intuitive. Hope that this helps other people like it helped me.

Comment: This was great.  The only thing is, once you've set ViewSource.Source to your ObservableCollection, you can no longer change your ObservableCollection in a BackgroundWorker. Or at least I couldn't.

Comment: It would also happen if you were binding the control directly to the ObservableCollection. IN both cases, you can actually makes changes to the collection, by simply invoking an action on the application dispatcher.

Comment: Hi Marc Wellman, I am trying to get your method of sorting with a WPF datagrid working but the datagrid doesn't even show the data I bound to it let alone sort.  Before I was doing a basic non sorting datagrid with gridName.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection; coupled with gridName.Items.Refresh(); and the grid loads the data properly using this method but when I switch to yours the datagrid shows no data at all.  I was thinking of opening a new post so I could show my code and then reference this post but not sure if that is a Faux Pas in the stackoverflow world.  Any advice?

Comment: It is working, but it takes much time to refresh. I have only 43 records in DataGrid

Comment: I have same question as @C

Comment: The Refresh() will make you lose the information which rows were selected before the Refresh().

Answer (score 21):

This is more for clarification than it is an answer, but WPF **always** binds to an `ICollectionView` and not the source collection. `CollectionViewSource` is just a mechanism used to create/retrieve the collection view.

Here's a great resource about the topic which should help you make better use of collection views in WPF: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387

Using `CollectionViewSource` in XAML can actually simplify your code some:

```xml
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase">

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding MySourceCollection}" x:Key="cvs">
          <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ColumnName" />
          </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
        
    ...
        
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Some people argue that when following the MVVM pattern, the view model should always expose the collection view but in my opinion, it just depends on the use case. If the view model is never going to directly interact with the collection view, it's just easier to configure it in XAML.

Comment: This is a good suggestion - the CollectionViewSource should either be a property in the code behind of the View (and can in turn bind to the ObservableCollection on the VM), or declare it as a local static resource as you've done.

Comment: This is the best solution, there's just one mistake in your XAML - it's "PropertyName" instead of "Property" in the SortDescription element.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. I just had a hard time figuring out the scm namespace. Here it is for people trying to find it: xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

Comment: That link is dead, but I found the text on [The Internet Archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150103043436/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/387#.VwVFQfkrKUk)

Answer (score 6):

The answer by sellmeadog is either overly complicated or out of date. It's super simple.  All you have to do is:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        Source="{Binding MyCollection}" 
        IsLiveSortingRequested="True" 
        x:Key="MyKey" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey} }" >...
```

Comment: Just a note, IsLiveSortingRequested requires .NET 4.5

Comment: How does it know which column to sort by?  Doesn't it require the CollectionViewSource SortDescription somewhere?

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention how it identifies the column to sort by..

Comment: According to the question, the user selects the sorting by clicking on a column header. In that case there is no need to defined the sorting in the CollectionViewSource.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any obviously easy ways, so I would try an Attached Behavior. It is a bit of a bastardization, but will give you what you want:

```
public static class DataGridAttachedProperty
{
     public static DataGrid _storedDataGrid;
     public static Boolean GetResortOnCollectionChanged(DataGrid dataGrid)
     {
         return (Boolean)dataGrid.GetValue(ResortOnCollectionChangedProperty);
     }

     public static void SetResortOnCollectionChanged(DataGrid dataGrid, Boolean value)
     {
         dataGrid.SetValue(ResortOnCollectionChangedProperty, value);
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exposes attached behavior that will trigger resort
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResortOnCollectionChangedProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ResortOnCollectionChangedProperty", typeof (Boolean),
         typeof(DataGridAttachedProperty),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnResortOnCollectionChangedChange));

    private static void OnResortOnCollectionChangedChange
        (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      _storedDataGrid = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
      if (_storedDataGrid == null)
        return;

      if (e.NewValue is Boolean == false)
        return;

      var observableCollection = _storedDataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection;
      if(observableCollection == null)
        return;
      if ((Boolean)e.NewValue)
        observableCollection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
      else
        observableCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private static void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.OldItems == e.NewItems)
        return;

      _storedDataGrid.Items.Refresh()
    }
}
```

Then, you can attach it via:

```
<DataGrid.Style>
  <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter 
      Property="AttachedProperties:DataGridAttachedProperty.ResortOnCollectionChangedProperty" 
                                    Value="true" 
      />
   </Style>
 </DataGrid.Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer but unfortunately I was not able to make it work. I managed it to attach your property to my DataGrid and to have the `_storedDataGrid.ItemsCollection.Refresh()` being called on every `CollectionChange` event of my underlying collection. But for some reason the DataGrid wouldn't sort. I am not sure but maybe it's because I am using multiple threads and I had some problems propagating the Refresh-call to the UIThread. Anyways I found another lucky solution that works very fine - see my own answer for that. Nevertheless, again thank you!

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else having this problem, this may get you started...
If you have a collection of INotifyPropertyChanged items, you can use this instead of ObservableCollection - it will refresh when individual items in the collection change:
note: since this flags the items as removed then readded (even though they aren't actually removed and added,) selections may get out of sync. It's good enough for my small personal projects, but it's not ready to release to customers...

```
public class ObservableCollection2<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection2()
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += ObservableCollection2_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void ObservableCollection2_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object o in e.OldItems)
                remove(o);
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object o in e.NewItems)
                add(o);
    }
    void add(object o)
    {
        INotifyPropertyChanged ipc = o as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if(ipc!=null)
            ipc.PropertyChanged += Ipc_PropertyChanged;
    }
    void remove(object o)
    {
        INotifyPropertyChanged ipc = o as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        if (ipc != null)
            ipc.PropertyChanged -= Ipc_PropertyChanged;
    }
    void Ipc_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs f;

        f = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, sender);
        base.OnCollectionChanged(f);
        f = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, sender);
        base.OnCollectionChanged(f);
    }
}
```