# Sort nodes of a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, telerik, radtreeview

I am using the telerik RadTreeView to show a hierarchy of folders. The user must be able to add/remove/rename folders in this tree. This works so far but the tree should be alphabetically sorted each time the tree is changed.

To sort the TreeView I am supposed to sort the underlying data model. This means the top level folders and recursively all children.

My underlying model is stored in a database and accessed using EF. It is basically an Entity "TreeFolder" with a 1:n association to itself. EF lets me access the child folders of a TreeFolder as EntityCollection.

My problem here is: How can I sort the EntityCollections? So far I know this is not possible - I should use a wrapper like a CollectionViewSource. This would mean I would need to create a new class "SortableTreeFolder" (or extend the partial class from EF) which holds such a CollectionViewSource. This means I would need to copy all children into this CollectionViewSource when the tree is loaded.

Is there a possibility to sort the TreeView model only using the EF navigation properties?

EDIT:
After trying out different things (thanks Uwy) I as well stumbled across this site: [Sorting EF Collection](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0075ec8b-71d8-43e8-af08-818c09548d41/sorting-an-ef-collection-in-datagrid?forum=wpf)

There it says:

> Although EntityCollection doesn't implement IList, it implements IListSource and CollectionViewSource will call IListSource.GetList method to create the view. EntityCollection.GetList will actually return an IBindingList object that doesn't support sort.
>   As a result, the collection view of the EntityCollection doesn't support sorting by default.

Obviously it is not possible to sort the TreeView model only using the EF navigation properties. I am still looking for a workaround besides managing a second (sortable) data structure.

Comment: By default, WPF item source bindings fallbacks to what `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()` gives (at least when it's on the same thread). You could try doing that recursively on your entities, adding a sort description.

Comment: Thank you. I see that GetDefaultView() should be declared in ICollectionView. When I check my CollectionView there is no such method though... Nor does it exist in the ICollectionView interface.

Comment: I am not sure about what you didn't get so I made a sample code in an answer to give you an idea of what I meant

Answer (score 1):

(From my previous comments)

By default, WPF item source bindings fallbacks to what CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView() gives (at least when it's on the same thread). You could try doing that recursively on your entities, adding a sort description.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{

    public void SetupCollectionView(IEnumerable<MyObject> entities)
    {
        foreach(var entity in entities)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(entity)
                .SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(MyObject.Header), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            this.SetupCollectionView(entity.Childs);
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<MyObject> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: GetDefaultView() returns null in my case. What does MyObject in your case look like? I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: MyObject is just your typical recursive entity, it's just given as a sample here, it could be anything like folder on a filesystem or a tree node in a database. CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView() returning null typically means the collection is null or you're running the call on another thread than the UI, try to use the dispatcher to run it on the main application thread.

Comment: I used the entity instead of the EntityCollection of the entity as parameter for GetDefaultView(). That's why I got null. I now get an ICollection back but it is not sortable. I guess I'll have to convert the EntityCollection into a list or so (something which is sortable) and keep both data structures up to date.

Comment: You should wrap your entity in a viewmodel for that case, exposing the childs in an observable collection or a list if you don't need collectionchanged notifications

Comment: For now I solved it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505283/re-sort-wpf-datagrid-after-bounded-data-has-changed